# jQuery datepicker questions

Tags: jquery, datepicker

First : 
Is it possible to set either an option or to easily change jQuery UI core code so the datepicker will always show a fixed amount of rows(/weeks) ?

Displaying a month takes either 5 or 6 rows/weeks, and the difference in height is not something I want using an inline datepicker. 
Answered: hardcode the variable numRows in ui.datepicker.js var numRows = 6;

Second: 
Is it also possible to change 'Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa' to
'S M T W T F S' ? 
Answered: dayNamesMin: ['S','M','T','W','T','F','S']

Third: 
Is it possible to have the month AND year in one and the same dropdown menu (between the arrows)? In the css file there is a line '
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year {width: 100%;}' which suggests it is possible, but I can't find the js code to enable this.

Fourth: 
And also, is it possible besides showing dates from other months, to make them selectable as well ? (non-selectable by default when using showOtherMonths: true)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First:

That will mean cutting off some days from a month. Do you really want this?

Second:

See the [daysNameMin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dayNamesMin) and [daysNameShort properties.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dayNamesShort)

Fourth:

These are selectable by default.

Comment: First: Which days are going to be cut off ? If I always want to display 6 rows, all days of the month are shown. Second:
Thanks for that link, I must have missed that one. Fourth:
They really are not selectable by default: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOtherMonths

Comment: You are right about the fourth one - I thought you meant using the numberOfMonths property.